# what does <unclassified> mean in windbg !address output

Tags: windows, memory, windbg

Example:

```
0:074> !address -summary


--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                  90919      7ec`34659000 (   7.923 Tb)           99.03%
<unclassified>                        95426       12`3c3e9000 (  72.941 Gb)  92.12%    0.89%
Heap                                    744        1`7ee50000 (   5.983 Gb)   7.56%    0.07%
Image                                  4303        0`0f890000 ( 248.563 Mb)   0.31%    0.00%
Stack                                   225        0`00de9000 (  13.910 Mb)   0.02%    0.00%
TEB                                      75        0`00096000 ( 600.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
ActivationContextData                    28        0`00025000 ( 148.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
NlsTables                                 1        0`00023000 ( 140.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
CsrSharedMemory                           1        0`00006000 (  24.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<unclassified>` is for allocations that are not further traceable to other memory managers and thus is allocated via `VirtualAlloc()` from WinDbg's point of view. In newer versions of WinDbg, this is called `<unknown>`.

There are different reasons for memory classified that way:

- direct calls to `VirtualAlloc()` of course
- allocations via the Windows Heap Manager that are larger than 512 kb (see the [statement by Sasha Goldshtein](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2015/10/23/large-win32-heap-allocations-go-directly-to-virtualalloc/)).
- allocations of the .NET runtime (which has its own heaps that are unknown to WinDbg until you use the special SOS extension)
- some versions of MSXML
- potential other memory managers, e.g. the heap manager from Java or Python (just a guess, I never verified)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, this is a wild guess, but things that can take up VA space that aren't on that list are directly calling VirtualAlloc, or memory-mapped files. [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) might prove to be more helpful here.