# Windbg <unclassified> memory Region

Tags: windows, memory, windbg

I wanted to determine where actually eax register points to[Stack or Heap].In below windbg out put !address out put shows that it unclassified.

```
0:014> r
eax=01198ce8 ebx=00000000 ecx=01198bf8 edx=00000000 esi=01196ed8 edi=01198160
eip=0710a501 esp=01e8fdc8 ebp=01e8fe28 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00000202
libmp4v2!MP4GetVideoProfileLevel+0x3bbb:
0710a501 e83eec0000      call    libmp4v2!MP4PrintVideoInfo+0xca2e (07119144)

0:014> d eax
01198ce8  76 69 64 65 00 04 38 00-04 00 02 00 cd 01 09 01  vide..8.........
01198cf8  47 50 41 43 20 49 53 4f-20 56 69 64 65 6f 20 48  GPAC ISO Video H
01198d08  61 6e 64 6c 65 72 00 00-0f 00 04 00 f1 01 08 01  andler..........
01198d18  e8 10 12 07 68 04 38 00-d8 6e 19 01 00 00 00 00  ....h.8..n......
01198d28  64 01 00 00 00 00 00 00-2c 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00  d.......,.......
01198d38  c0 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00-6d 69 6e 66 00 00 38 00  ........minf..8.
01198d48  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
01198d58  f0 86 19 01 ff 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

0:014> !address eax


Failed to map Heaps (error 80004005)
Usage:                  <unclassified>
Allocation Base:        01130000
Base Address:           01130000
End Address:            011a1000
Region Size:            00071000
Type:                   00020000    MEM_PRIVATE
State:                  00001000    MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000004    PAGE_READWRITE
```

I want to know what does that mean??

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876516/windbg-address-summary for some information about what `<unclassified>` means.

Comment: windbg 6.12? [Failed to map Heaps (error 80004005)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c8207dba-78ba-46d0-99c6-be7db06d7ead/resolve-unclassified-entries-in-windbg?forum=windbg)

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like an application that has read a MP4 video into memory. There are several indicators for this:

1. In the memory dump we see a "vide" (video) section and a "minf" (media info) section. There could also be "soun" (sound) later in the MP4 file.
2. The call stack says something about the `libmp4v2` DLL

Regarding the `<unclassified>` (`<unknown>`in newer versions of WinDbg), I see the following potential reasons:

1. The video file is larger than 512 kB and thus an allocation (e.g. from C++) via the Windows Heap Manager is not considered as more efficient than a direct call to `VirtualAlloc()`. This is [described by Sasha Goldshtein](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2015/10/23/large-win32-heap-allocations-go-directly-to-virtualalloc/).
2. The memory was allocated by .NET, which has its own heap manager, built on top of `VirtualAlloc()`.

See also here on SO: [what does `<unclassified>` mean ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2210270/480982)